# Checking to find out if an element contains more than 1 classname

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need your help.

Using pure javascript and not jQuery, how do you find out if an element contains more than 1 classname.

ie.

```
if (#test has the classname = "classA and classB" then { alert(true) }
else { alert(false) }
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="test" "class="classA classB">
```

Comment: You can use either [className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className) which gives you a space separated list, or the newer [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList) which gives you a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question (or rather your title) is a little unclear. I'm guessing what you are asking is not if an element has more than one class, but whether or not an element has 2 *specific* classes assigned to it (`ClassA` and `ClassB`):

```js
var classNames = document.getElementById("test").className.split(" ");

if (classNames.indexOf("ClassA") >= 0 && classNames.indexOf("ClassB") >= 0) {
  // test has both class A and class B
  alert(true);
} else {
  alert(false);
}
```

```html
<div id="test" class="ClassA ClassB"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" id="test" class="classA classB" />
```

---

```
var classArray = document.getElementById('test').classList;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use just `split`:

```
var classes = document.getElementById("test").className.split(' ');
```

Please check the following:

```js
var classes = document.getElementById("test").className.split(' ');

alert(classes);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="test" class="classA classB">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Pure JavaScript:**

```
// Consecutive spaces in the class attribute will cause this to return the wrong number
document.getElementById("test").className.split(" ").length
```

In the above code you'd want to loop through the result of the split method and remove empty array entries before getting the length of the array.

**DOM API** (http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist)

```
document.querySelector("#test").classList.length
or
document.getElementById("test").classList.length
```

**For the psuedo code**

```
var classList = document.querySelector("#test").classList;
if (classList.contains("classA") && classList.contains("classB")) {
    alert(true);
} else {
    alert(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, here a example [fiddlejs](http://jsfiddle.net/689xn5s0/)

```
Array.prototype.contains = function(obj) {
    var i = this.length;
    while (i--) {
        if (this[i] == obj) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
} 

var test = document.getElementById("test").classList

if (test.contains("classA") && test.contains("classC")){
    alert(true) 
}
else { 
   alert(false) 
}
```

Comment: Why on Earth would you reinvent the wheel like this?

Answer (score 0):

First, get the class attribute:

```
var classAttr = document.getElementById("test").className;
```

Split it into an array:

```
var classes = classAttr.split(" +");
```

Finally, check that both classes are in the array.  With ECMAScript 7:

```
if (classes.includes("classA") && classes.includes("classB") {
  alert(true);
} else {
  alert(false);
}
```

Or with older JS:

```
if ((classes.indexOf("classA") > -1) && (classes.indexOf("classB") > -1)) {
  alert(true);
} else {
  alert(false);
}
```